# How to solve vulnerabilities issue in gulp?

Tags: gulp-sass

When I run "npm install gulp-cli -g" it says 3 low vulnerability issues. Is there a ways to fix this?

```
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

changed 265 packages, and audited 266 packages in 22s

6 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

3 low severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:   
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
```